# QLineEdit Japanese/Chinese character  not displayed

Tags: string, qt, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have a QLineEdit where user will enter a name (not necessary a human name) and the character is not rendered.
It looks like:

[image]

How do I have to configure the QLineEdit encoding to get that character visible?

Comment: did you tried `QLocale` ? as `lineEdit.setLocale(QLocale::Chinese);`

Comment: still not working...

Comment: QtCreator (3.2, Qt 5.3) itself is not able to show that character properly. That version of Qt fully supports Unicode 6.2. Make sure the character is defined for 6.2: http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.2.0/charts/CodeCharts.pdf .

Comment: On OS X 10.9 the most recent Safari doesn't show this character either, so most likely you're doing something wrong on your end. First make sure that the character is visible in the title of this post. Edit your post's title to fix it. Once that's done, we can further test it. Also give us the Unicode name/code point for the character.

Comment: @Kuba Ober, the character's unicode is: U+24B62. A lot more information can be found here: http://graphemica.com/%F0%A4%AD%A2 .

Comment: This is not a locale issue. Qt (all its UI components) are Unicode aware so you should be able to transparently use unicode characters without any problems as long as the font contains its graphical representation. I think the problem is that the ideograph was introduced after Unicode 6.2 . (BTW, the same version OSX 10.9 supports).

Comment: You claim that the application font supports this character. Are you sure that the correct font is in fact selected in the line edit? Use `QFontInfo` (**not QFont!**) to determine how the QFont request was resolved into an actual font.

Comment: @mchuervo There's something to that. On 10.9, the character is not displayed by Safari in the webpage contents, but it is displayed in the URL bar...

Comment: TL;DR: It seems that at the moment at least Qt 5.3 is still unable to deal with this character. Try with the most recent version. You can easily patch Qt to add support for this character, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the solution is quite simple. It is needed to upgrade to Qt 5.5.1.

The symbol is also correctly displayed in the editor of Qt Creator 3.5.1 that is based on Qt 5.5.1. In Qt Creator 3.2.1 (based on Qt 5.3.2) the symbol is not displayed.

The symbol is displayed as rectangle in UI controls of Qt 5.3.2. However, it is correctly displayed in labels and in other text controls if the project is built by Qt 5.5.1.

---

It appears that at least Qt 5.5.1 is needed to find such character if it is not present in the default font of the UI control.

The default font fall back mechanism is implemented only in Qt 5.5.1, so even Q 5.5.0 cannot properly display the character if it is not found in the selected font.

I guess that the improvement is done by the Qt commit [5e3e34731b7880ac775e8f1fa156ce016e6820f1 Default implementation for QPlatformFontDatabase::fallbacksForFamily()](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?h=5.5&id=5e3e34731b7880ac775e8f1fa156ce016e6820f1) (maybe in connection with previous [[QFontDatabase] Defer the fallback families list initialization](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?h=5.5&id=735cd0ccf3e51f9b3f0e9d30df08899ae54bf7ab)).

---

However, it is still possible to display that character in older Qt versions (even in Qt4). It possible to set manually font that supports needed symbols.

For example, there is font "SimSun-ExtB" in Windows that supports CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B. That font can be set manually to specific UI widgets or to the entire application:

```
QFont CJK_ExtB("SimSun-ExtB");
// font for widget
ui->lineEdit->setFont(CJK_ExtB);
// or default application font
QApplication::setFont(CJK_ExtB);
```

---

Of course to display a character it should be available in some system font or in application loaded font. Windows 7 by default has font for `CJK Ext.B`, but to display symbols from `CJK-C` or `CJK-D` some other font is needed. For example, there is a free Unicode CJK font [BabelStone Han](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) that covers some such symbols. It is possible to load it manually for application:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("c:/test/BabelStoneHan.ttf");
```

Now the application is able to find automatically `CJK-B` symbols in Windows system font "SimSun-ExtB" and `CJK-C` symbols in "BabelStoneHan" if Qt 5.5.1 is used.

---

The font fallback improvement in Qt 5.5.1 mainly affects Windows, since in Ubuntu Linux the application is able to find proper fonts for symbols even with older Qt versions (if fonts are added by `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont`, since there is no system fonts for CJK extensions by default).

Comment: @JacobKrieg Note that anyway some font should be available in the system that is able to display required characters. It may be needed to deliver some fonts with application, since by default operating systems do not have fonts for all CJK extensions.